# Text/Font rendering in Web browsers. How is it achieved?

Tags: html, pdf, text, fonts, browser

Premise: I know that PDF text is rendered by means of a C library that understands fonts and is able to render them in graphical form. For example, open-source PDF libraries (like poppler or mupdf) rely on freetype2, which is responsible to render the fonts.
Question: I would like to know which method is used in HTML Web browsers to render text and fonts.

Answer (score 1):

PDF's typically include everything necessary in order to render the document, including fonts. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format)

> Portable Document Format (PDF) is a file format used to represent
>   documents in a manner independent of application software, hardware,
>   and operating systems.[2] Each PDF file encapsulates a complete
>   description of a fixed-layout flat document, including the text,
>   fonts, graphics, and other information needed to display it.

Browsers typically (hopefully) follow standards defined by the W3C. For instance, in http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/, we have the following:

> Font resources may be local, installed on the system on which a user
>   agent is running, or downloadable. For local font resources
>   descriptive information can be obtained directly from the font
>   resource. For downloadable font resources (sometimes referred to as
>   web fonts), the descriptive information is included with the reference
>   to the font resource. Families of fonts typically don't contain a
>   single face for each possible variation of font properties. The CSS
>   font selection mechanism describes how to match a given set of CSS
>   font properties to a given font face.

If you really want to dig into the guts of how browsers render fonts, become familiar with http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/.

So, CSS provides the web-designer the ability to specify a prioritization of what fonts to use. For instance, the W3C provides the following example:

```
body { 
    font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; 
}
```

> If Helvetica is available it will be used when rendering. If neither
>   Helvetica nor Verdana is present, then the user-agent-defined sans
>   serif font will be used.

Comment: Do you think the system used in browsers could be faster, given a common font, to render text, than pdf libraries? How can I find this information?

Comment: The current generation of browsers is very fast. My gut feeling is that if you aren't going to see any speed differences playing around with different variations of fonts. As to your question specifically, it would depend on the browser itself, and I'm not sure if that information is published. You would have to research the differences in the [layout engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layout_engine) for each browser.

Comment: So, in principle, each different engine could rely on a different C library or source code portion to render font? Isn't there a common linked library? Should I look myself inside WebKit or Gecko, for example, to understand what is used to render fonts?

Comment: Bingo... And that is a rabbit hole that probably isn't going to provide much bang for the buck, other than having a better understanding of how those engines work. You will probably be fruitless though, in determining how to have your fonts rendered faster. However, if you determine some improvements, you might want to share them with the greater community, maybe even contribute to some of the open source engines.

Comment: I am not interested in comparing the font rendering performances between browsers or between fonts, I want to know if text rendering in browsers is really faster than text rendering in PDF viewers as I think (because tested some PDF libraries and they are slow). I just want that someone says it is true and why.

Comment: Sure. Although you might want to narrow your question down then. There are many different browser engines, and many different PDF viewers. There is nothing prohibiting each one from using their own code for font rendering.

Comment: There are so many variables involved in this so it is not possible to give a definitive answer. The speed of font rendering is not affected by the file format, HTML or PDF, although PDF being oriented towards typography might require higher quality in font rendering than HTML. The speed comes from the implementation, FreeType is software based, the font engine in Adobe Reader is hardware accelerated. Also browsers might use the underlying platform (Windows, Linux, etc) font engine which again might be hardware accelerated.